# How to cast listview object

Tags: asp.net, list, view

I'm wondering how to cast a `listview` object to a `datetime`. Is there a way to do this on front end markup page?

Here's my code below from part of the `listview` functionality. This code below doesn't work properly.

```
<asp:ListView  ID="listviewAttachments" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="announcementPost">
            <td class="posted">
                <h6>Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("DateModified")).Day<span><asp:Label   ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("DateModified")).Month %>' />  </span></h6>   
            </td>
```

Comment: You should go back and accept some answers to your previous questions. It would give people more incentive to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not casting a ListView object to DateTime. What you are doing there is trying to cast one of your properties to DateTime

Try this:

```
<%=Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("DateModified")).Day %>
```